# when to register to model events in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my `backbone.js` app I need to update a specific view field when a model changes. For example:

```
this.model.bind("change:name", function() {
    $("#name", this.el).text(this.model.get("name"))
})
```

where should I put this code? If I put it in the `initialize()` then maybe the event is called before `render()` is. This seems a little dirty. In particular I may need the event to update UI elements that are only created in render.

If I put this code in `render()` then this seems again not appropriate. For example, I may call `render()` a few times but this logic should only be registered once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding the event in initialize is the easiest way, so I would just make your function smart enough not to have an error if rendering has not happened yet.

A few other recommendations:

- Make the function part of the view prototype.
- Your code as given will not work because `this` is wrong inside the callback, so you need to pass the third parameter.
- `bind` is deprecated. Use `on` instead.
- `$(..., this.el)` is equivalent to `this.$(...)`
- Callbacks are passed the new value automatically, so calling `get` again is extra work.

---

```
initialize: function(options){
  this.model.on('change:name', this.changeName, this);
},

changeName: function(model, name){
  this.$('#name').text(name);
}
```

Comment: `this.$(...)` (or `this.$el.find(...)`) also has the advantage of not hiding the all important `this.el` at the end of the argument list where it is easily missed.